# py2exe, problems

Tags: python, windows-7, py2exe

I'm attempting to convert a .py file to a .exe file. However, I get a weird output.

Output:

```
usage: module1 [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: module1 --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: module1 --help-commands
   or: module1 cmd --help

error: no commands supplied
```

My code:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['newstyledemo.py'])
```

Also when this is done where do I recover the .exe file? I'd like to place it on a flash drive for redistribution.

I'm running Python 2.6 on Windows-7, BTW

Comment: The .exe file ends up under dist directory. Also, could you try setup(console=[{'newstyledemo' : 'newstyledemo.py'}])

Answer (score 1):

Useing [Gui2exe](http://code.google.com/p/gui2exe) can be smart,i use it to both console and gui.

Here is a script i have used,and have worked ok.

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import sys

if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    sys.argv.append("py2exe")

setup( options = {"py2exe": {"compressed": 1, "optimize": 2, "ascii": 1, "bundle_files": 3}},
       zipfile = None,

       ## data_files = ['apple.jpg', 'cheese.jpg'],

       #Your py-file can use windows or console
       windows = [{"script": 'my.py'}])
```